# RWordPress knit2wp Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to site.com:443

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to publish a `.Rmd` file as post on my website which uses WordPress. I get the following error:

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
>     Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to meshry.com:443

I don't know what it means nor what to do about it. Your help will appreciated. Here is my code:

```
library(knitr)
library(RWordPress)

options(WordpressLogin = c(myusername = "mypassword"),
        WordpressURL = "https://meshry.com/xmlrpc.php")

knit2wp("mypost.RmD" ,
        title = "My Post" ,
        publish = FALSE ,
        action = "newPost")
```

Comment: see the comment here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/publishing-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection-to-api-shinyapps-io-443/45910

Comment: I saw that post before posting this question. I had checked the box of "Rstudio R Session" under the windows defender firewall as suggested in one of the comments. I had also reinstalled the `rsconnect` package. Unfortunatly, I still got the same error: `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to meshry.com:443`. Is there something I missed reading that discussion? I am not technical, so there could be some simple that I am missing.